# Matching an objects 2 dimensional array using includes() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I am trying to match the user input array (this.scoreO, or this scoreX) arrays to the this.winningBoard array, but not with exact values. The values might not be in order, and I want to match the set of three even if there are more values in the "score" array.

So for example, maybe

```
this.scoreO = [9,5,2,1]
```

I would like it to trigger a match with [1,5,9] see below array

```
this.winningBoard = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[3,5,7],**[1,5,9]**]
```

Here is the code:

```
function Game (player) {

this.winningBoard = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [1,4,7],
    [2,5,8],
    [3,6,9],
    [3,5,7],
    [1,5,9]
]   
this.scoreO = [];
this.scoreX = [];

}

Game.prototype.findWinner2 = function() {

for(i = 0; i < this.winningBoard.length; i++) {

    if (this.winningBoard[i].includes(this.scoreO) === true) {

        //display player 1 "O" is the winner


    } else if (this.winningBoard[i].includes(this.scoreX) === true) {

        //display player 2 "X" is the winner


    } 
}
}
```

I keep getting a false outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a combination of `some`, `every`, and `includes` (if you can use es6):

```js
var winningBoard = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9],
  [1,4,7],
  [2,5,8],
  [3,6,9],
  [3,5,7],
  [1,5,9],
];

var score0 = [9,5,2,1];

console.log(winningBoard.some(board => board.every(x => score0.includes(x))))
```

You can read this as: see if there is *some* element of `winningBoard` such that for *every* item in that element, `score0` *includes* that item.

EDIT: Some added explanation (from the inside out):

`x => score0.includes(x)`

This is a function that returns **true if the array `score0` has `x` as an element.** That one is pretty straightforward. In this case, `x` is just a number.

`board => board.every(x => score0.includes(x))`

`every` returns true only when it's callback is true for *every* element of the array. So since `board` is one of your winning number arrays (eg: `[1,5,9]`), this part will be **true if *every* number in that board is included in `score0`**.

Finally: `winningBoard.some(board => board.every(x => score0.includes(x)))`

`some`, being sort of like the inverse of `every`, returns true if the callback function returns true for *any* of the array elements. So this is **true if any of the boards have all their elements included in `score0`**, which is exactly the condition you want to check.

Last: the syntax `x => x*2` is a shorthand for writing `function(x) { return x*2 }` (with some scope differences, not important here). You can read about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Wow, thanks CRice. Works well. If you could explain a little deeper that would be great. it works, but I don't fully understand what you did with board and x ( these are arrow functions?)

Comment: @Leslie I edited the post to include some extra explanation (I admit I took some things for granted originally). If anything is still unclear, please don't hesitate to ask for further clarification. Glad I could help. Thanks!

Comment: You rock @CRice! Very helpful - Thanks a bunch! I tried to upvote you but I'm still a pion with too little reputation.

Comment: @Leslie If this answered your question to your satisfaction I would very much appreciate an accept and a vote. ;) You should still be able to vote with low rep even if it doesn't affect the visible score.